# INSERT INTO error in mysql (desc included)

Tags: mysql, database, macos

I got tables like below and I am trying to INSERT data.

```
 mysql> desc subscribers
    -> ;
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | smallint(6) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| email   | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| comment | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Data insert

```
INSERT INTO `subscribers` VALUES (1, ‘someone@gmail.com’, ‘thanks’);
```

But It gives me an error.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com’, ‘ thanks’)' at line 1
```

Does anybody see an error??

Comment: Your editor/terminal/something is converting [`'` U+0027 APOSTROPHE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0027) characters (which MySQL recognises as string literal quotes) into [`‘` U+2018 LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2018) and [`’` U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019) (which MySQL does not so recognise, and therefore instead parses the resulting language element as an object identifier).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are surrounding your strings to be inserted with some sort of apostrophe instead of a single quote.  Use this instead (and copy it verbatim from this answer):

```
INSERT INTO `subscribers`
VALUES (1, 'someone@gmail.com', 'thanks');
```

Comment: Thaks I should have set my text editior's smart quote!

Comment: I will quote you as having said that (no pun intended).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the curly single quote.  But, to prevent future errors, you should always include the column list in the `insert`:

```
INSERT INTO `subscribers`(id, email, comment)
    VALUES (1, 'someone@gmail.com', 'thanks');
```

In fact, a natural way to create the table is using an auto-incremented `id`. If you did then, then the `INSERT` would look like:

```
INSERT INTO `subscribers`(email, comment)
    VALUES ('someone@gmail.com', 'thanks');
```

The `id` would be assigned automatically.